# Не отображается форма во время designe time

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть общий класс ReportForm наследуемый от Form, от которого созданы несколько производных классов-форм:

```
     public class ReportForm : Form
    {
        protected DataTable _dtDepartments;
        protected DataTable _dtAllow;

        public ReportForm()
    {
        this.Load += ReportForm_Load;
    }

    private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dtAllow = MainForm._user.GetDepartments();
        _dtDepartments = _dtAllow.Copy();
    }

...
```

Все эти созданные классы не отображаются во время разработки из-за строки _dtAllow = MainForm._user.GetDepartments() т.к. _user - экземпляр класса, который создается уже во время RunTime.
Как добиться того, чтобы без изменения остальной структуры программы (в частности создания экземпляра класса _user) отображались формы во время разработки. Сразу прошу не предлагать, просто закомментировать данную строку.

upd: После попытки создать события load ошибка остается.

Comment: Перенести эти строки из конструктора в событие `Form_Load`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я попробовал, но подпись происходит все равно в конструкторе, ошибка остается

Comment: Что за подпись, о чём речь? Покажите больше кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил код в вопрос